# Sorting a keyword field alphabetically on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers, elasticsearch-7

While applying sort on a `keyword` type field, it goes lexicographical and for the given data:

```
AAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAaaaa
Aaaaaa
jjjjjaaa
jjjjjAAA
JJJJJJjjjj
aaaJJJJJjjjj
```

After sort becomes:

```
AAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAaaaa
Aaaaaa
JJJJJJjjjj
aaaJJJJJjjjj
jjjjjAAA
jjjjjaaa
```

**Expected:** Is it possible to get a sort based on alphabetical order?

```
aaaJJJJJjjjj
Aaaaaa
AAAAaaaa
AAAAAAAAAAA
jjjjjaaa
jjjjjAAA
JJJJJJjjjj
```

Please not that, I have already tried the `lowercase` filter option and got the below result which is not my requirement:

```
Aaaaaa
AAAAaaaa
AAAAAAAAAAA
aaaJJJJJjjjj
jjjjjaaa
jjjjjAAA
JJJJJJjjjj
```

Comment: So you basically want lowercase words to appear before uppercased ones, i.e. `a` before `A`, then `b` before `B`, etc?

Comment: That's right @Val